# How to prevent my MFC dialog-based app from closing after ESC key, but allow other controls to process it?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I can't seem to find a working solution how to block my dialog-based MFC app from closing after a user hits ESC on the keyboard. I keep finding code where people simply override `PreTranslateMessage` notifications and block all `WM_KEYDOWN` messages for `VK_ESCAPE`, but that doesn't work for me because this approach blocks **all** ESC keystrokes in the app. So for instance, when a user opens a drop-down list and wants to close it with ESC key, it will be also blocked. Or, the same would happen if someone opens a popup menu or a date-time/calendar control and tries to dismiss it with the ESC keystroke, etc.

So my question, how to prevent **only my dialog** from closing after ESC keystroke?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Esc` gets automatically routed to your dialog through `WM_COMMAND` with an id of `IDCANCEL`. In `dlgcore.cpp` there is a default handler that will terminate your dialog (and hence the application in your case) like this:

```
void CDialog::OnCancel()
{
    EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
}
```

To stop that happening, simply add an `IDCANCEL` handler yourself. For example, in your dialog header add the method signature:

```
afx_msg void OnCancelOverride();
```

In your dialogs message map, add routing for `IDCANCEL`:

```
ON_COMMAND(IDCANCEL,OnCancelOverride)
```

And finally add the `OnCancelOverride` implementation. This sample implementation doesn't exit if `Esc` is down but does allow exit from the system menu 'Close' option.

```
void CMyDlg::OnCancelOverride() 
{
  // call base implementation if escape is not down

  if((GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)==0)
    OnCancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can directly override OnCancel method and write nothing.
2. add `ON_WM_CLOSE()` to message map so that you can quit app by click right top X button.
3. add a method `afx_msg void OnClose ()` in dialog class header.
4. add code like following in dialog class cpp:

   `afx_msg void CDialogXXX::OnClose ()
   {
       PostQuitMessage (0) ;
       CDialog::OnClose () ;
   }`